# need help connecting to RDS from local and EC2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am trying to connect to RDS from my `localhost` and `ec2` server. 
I can connect fine with `MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE` but i cant seem to connect with `PHP`.
They are in the same zone and security group.

```
$dbName = "*******-****.***************.**-****-*.rds.amazonaws.com:3306";
$dbTable = "myTable";
$dbUser = "myUser";
$dbPass = "*********";

define("HOST", $dbName);
define("DBUSER", $dbUser);
define("PASS", $dbPass);
define("DB", $dbTable);
$conn = new mysqli(HOST, DBUSER, PASS, DB) or  die();
```

these are the errors
`Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [<a href='mysqli.mysqli'>mysqli.mysqli</a>]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.`
`Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [<a href='mysqli.mysqli'>mysqli.mysqli</a>]: [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (trying to connect via tcp://*******-****.***************.**-****-*.rds.amazonaws.com:3306)`
`Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [<a href='mysqli.mysqli'>mysqli.mysqli</a>]: (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.`
the endpoint works fine as i said with the client, not on browser. 
but what does this error mean, and how would i start debugging this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the security group for your amazon ec2 in your amazon admin console. please check you have opened the port for mysql (i.e 3306)

Comment: i took out 3306 and it worked `*******-****.***************.**-****-*.rds.amazonaws.com`

Comment: The 3306 is a port for mysql. In the amazon instance you have to open the port for mysql,apache and what ever you need otherwise you cant access those services.